# List subnets in an AWS by VPC ID

Tags: python, boto3

I need to list the subnets in a specific VPC in AWS.

I am getting this error when I do:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_create_ec2.py", line 253, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_create_ec2.py", line 249, in main
    create_instances()
  File ".\aws_create_ec2.py", line 146, in create_instances
    subnet_list = ec2_client.describe_subnets(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 272, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 548, in _make_api_call
    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 596, in _convert_to_request_dict
    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\validate.py", line 297, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "VpcIds", must be one of: Filters, SubnetIds, DryRun, NextToken, MaxResults
```

I'm using these commands:

```
 vpc_id = input("Enter the vpc id: ")
 subnet_list = ec2_client.describe_subnets(
     VpcIds=[
         vpc_id,
       ]
    )
```

How can I filter for the VPC I want correctly with this command?

Also how can I validate the user input with a regex so that it fits the right format? For example so that the user input matches something resembling: `vpc-68b1ff12`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kinda difficult to tell what code was running that failed but I'm thinking this could be accomplished in two steps... first list all `VPC`s then list all the `subnets` in each `VPC`

Something like this:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(region_name='us-east-1')
ec2_resource = session.resource("ec2")
ec2_client = session.client("ec2")
subnet_ids = []
for vpc in ec2_resource.vpcs.all():
    # here you can choose which subnet based on the id
    if vpc.id == 'vpc-abcd1234':
        for subnet in vpc.subnets.all():
            subnet_ids.append(subnet.id)
# the result of this call has the data you're looking for
print(ec2_client.describe_subnets(SubnetIds=subnet_ids))
```

To validate the input you might use a regex like this:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('vpc-\w{8}$')
print(pattern.match('vpc-abcd1'))
print(pattern.match('vpc-abcd1234'))
print(pattern.match('vpc-abcd1-34'))
print(pattern.match('vpc-abcd134567890'))
print(pattern.match('apc-1a2b3c4d'))
print(pattern.match('vpc-1a2b3c4d'))
```

Would print:

```
None
<re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='vpc-abcd1234'>
None
None
None
<re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='vpc-1a2b3c4d'>
```

to insure your input is valid call the validation in a loop, for example:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('vpc-\w{8}$')

def get_input():
    found = input("vpc id:")
    match = pattern.match(found)
    while not match:
        found = input('vpc id:')
        match = pattern.match(found)

    return found
```

Answer (score 5):

The error message means `VpcIds` is not a valid parameter for `describe_subnets`.  The list of valid parameters are documented [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_subnets).

Another way of getting the subnets in a VPC is:

```
subnets = boto3.resource("ec2").subnets.filter(
    Filters=[{"Name": "vpc-id", "Values": [vpc_id]}]
)
subnet_ids = [sn.id for sn in subnets]
```

Comment: Imo this should be the accepted answer. The current accepted answer is a very round about way of getting subnets in a VPC

Answer (score 1):

The function `describe_subnets` can also be used like this:

```
 vpc_id = "my-vpc-id"
 client = boto3.client("ec2")
 subnet_list = client.describe_subnets(
     Filters=[{"Name":"vpc-id", "Values":[vpc_id]}]
 )
```

Full documentation here https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_subnets